# Qt QGraphicsView Scrolling causes items to randomly disappear

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am having issues with a weird bug which occurs after you adjust the size of a QGraphicsItem.
Here is a YouTube video showing the issue: https://youtu.be/gp1lQTkPf54

In my application, a slider is used to adjust the horizontal zoom of all the regions on the QGraphicsScene. I have made sure to call `prepareGeometryChange();` when I am changing the geometry of a region and call `update();` but that has not helped. It seems to affect regions that are being rendered out of view from the user.

Code:

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    RegionGraphicsItem *rgi = new RegionGraphicsItem(ui->graphicsView->scene());
    itemList.append(rgi);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(rgi);
    rgi->setHScaleFactor(ui->horizontalSlider->value());
}

void MainWindow::test() {
    QWidget test;
    test.show();
}

void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
        itemList[i]->setHScaleFactor(value);
    }

}
```

mainwindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "regiongraphicsitem.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    QList<RegionGraphicsItem*> itemList;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value);

private:
    void test();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

regiongraphicsitem.cpp

```cpp
#include "regiongraphicsitem.h"

RegionGraphicsItem::RegionGraphicsItem(QGraphicsScene *_scene) : QGraphicsItem()
{
    regionColor = QColor::fromRgb(255,255,255);
    setFlags(ItemIsMovable);
    waveFormColor = regionColor.darker(80);

    outlineColor = QColor("#0f0f0f");
    selectedColor = selectedColor.lighter(30);

    hScaleFactor = 100;
    mainBrush = QBrush(regionColor);
    mainPen = QPen(outlineColor, 1);

    gridLength = 5;
    height = 56;
    oldPos = pos();
    scene = _scene;

    this->prepareGeometryChange();
    gridLocation = 5;
    setY((0 * 60) + 1);
}


QRectF RegionGraphicsItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0, 0, float(gridLength * hScaleFactor), float(height));
}

void RegionGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(widget);

    QRectF rect = boundingRect();

    painter->setBrush(mainBrush);
    painter->setPen(mainPen);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(rect, 5, 5);

    painter->setPen(mainPen);

    if (selected) {
        painter->setBrush(QBrush(mainPen.color()));
        painter->drawRoundedRect(QRect(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), 20), 5, 5);
        painter->drawRect(QRect(rect.x(), rect.y() + 5, rect.width(), 15));
    }


    QFont font = scene->font();
    font.setPixelSize(10);
    font.setBold(true);
    QFontMetricsF fontMetrics(font);
    QString text = "TEST";
    int heightFont = fontMetrics.boundingRect(text).height();
    if (selected) {
        painter->setPen(QPen(mainBrush.color(), 1));
    }
    painter->drawText(5, heightFont + 3, text);
    if (pressed == false ) {
        setX((gridLocation - 1) * hScaleFactor);
    }
}


void RegionGraphicsItem::setHScaleFactor(int value) {
    prepareGeometryChange();
    hScaleFactor = value;
    update();
}
```

regiongraphicsitem.h

```cpp
#ifndef RegionGraphicsItem_H
#define RegionGraphicsItem_H

#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QColor>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QPen>
#include <QtGui/QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

#include <QDebug>
#include <stdint.h>

class RegionGraphicsItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    RegionGraphicsItem(QGraphicsScene *_scene);
    float getGridLocation();
    void setHScaleFactor(int value);

protected:

    QColor outlineColor;
    QColor selectedColor;
    QColor regionColor;
    QColor waveFormColor;

    bool selected;

    int penWidth;
    int rounded;

    QBrush mainBrush;
    QBrush waveformBrush;
    QPen mainPen;

    int height;
    float gridLength;

    bool pressed = false;
    QPointF oldPos, oldMousePos;
    int oldTrackIndex;
    float gridLocation;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;

    int oldHScaleFactor;

    virtual QRectF boundingRect() const override;
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;

private:
    int hScaleFactor;

};

#endif // RegionGraphicsItem_H
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add a `RegionGraphicItem` to the `QGraphicsScene`
2. Increase the slider until the region is off screen
3. Decrease the slider and the region will not be visible. <-- This is the issue.

[image: Animated image showing the region not appearing when re-adjusting the size]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I've made a simple demo illustrating the issue. If you click on add, increase the slider to max and resize the window so it isn't visible, when you start to decrease then slider, the region will not re appear. https://github.com/tom-23/Qt-Scroll-Bug-Demo

Comment: The MRE should not depend on an external resource since if it breaks it makes your post useless. The MRE must be in your post, please read [ask]

Comment: @eyllanesc all fixed and added steps to reproduce

Comment: Could you show images of the error that you indicate

Comment: @eyllanesc I've included a gif in the question. When I decrease the slider, the white rectangle disappears when it shouldn't do.

Comment: The cause of the error is `setX((gridLocation - 1) * hScaleFactor);`, you cannot modify the position in the paint method so I think it is an incorrect implementation of something that you do not indicate, what is the objective of that line of code? Could you give more detail of how you want the item to behave to show you the correct implementation. That is not a Qt bug but a bad implementation on your part

Comment: @eyllanesc bad implementation on my part I'm afraid, seems to all be good now. Thanks for the help and I've also learned a bit about writing good stack overflow questions too.